# Why is my unity quality of the objects low and how can I change it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, youtube

I am a beginner and I am learning by brackeys tutorials. But I noticed some differences of the qualities.
Here is my unity project
[My Unity Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV9nc.png)

Here is brackeys unity project
[Brackeys Unity Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lefc.png)

As you see my project has not got smooth and quality edges like brackeys.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Smooth Quality Edges is called Antialiasing. And it is used via the PostProcessing package.

- Install the Post Processing package via the Package Manager (Window->Package Manager).
- Create a Post Processing Volume, set it to certain layer (create one called PostProcessing for example). Make it global.
- Add a Post Processing Layer component to your camera, set the layer of the Volume you just created and check the antialiasing checkbox.

Quality Settings have several predefined quality levels, so also check the desired quality levels have antialiasing enabled via (Edit->Project Settings->Quality).

And that's it. You have Smooth Quality Edges.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I installed the package but i don't know how to set it to a certain layer and make it global. And also there is no checkbox to check in antialiasing. It has different kinds of options. And I want to know why brackeys didnt go through all these.